# Form submission not working properly from wordpress page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to make an insert form directly inside wordpress post, the code is working partly fine i.e. it is adding blank row in "test" table in "webdatabase" with every submission but not adding any value in name and rollno column, it is also not displaying any error.
Please help so that value submitted through form can be inserted in to "test" table, thanks in advance.

My form with php code is as under:

```
<form action="http://localhost/wordpress" method="POST">
        Name:<br><input type="text" name="name" value=""><br>
        Roll No:<br><input type="text" name="rollno" value=""><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php

        $testname = $_POST['name'];
        $testrollno = $_POST['rollno']; 

        $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root", "","webdatabase");


        $sql = "INSERT INTO test (name,rollno) VALUES (' " . $testname . " ', '" . $testrollno . "')";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $conn->close(); 
    ?>
```

My table structure in mysql database is shown as under:

```
Column    Type
ID       int(15)             
name     varchar(20)             
rollno   varchar(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the “isset” function on any variable to determine if it has been set or not. You can use this function on the $_POST array to determine if the variable was posted or not. This is often applied to the submit button value, so

The HTML will be;

```
<form action="http://localhost/wordpress" method="POST">
    Name:<br><input type="text" name="name" value=""><br>
    Roll No:<br><input type="text" name="rollno" value=""><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and PHP will be;

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
        $testname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $testrollno = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['rollno']); 
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root", "","webdatabase");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (name,rollno) VALUES (' " . $testname . " ', '" . $testrollno . "')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $conn->close(); 
    }

?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘{‘ in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\includes\runtime.php(42) : eval()’d code on line 8

Comment: missed a closing bracket, typo mistake,  code in answer updated, please replace with old code

Comment: Now not giving an error but also not working, I think there might be error in my sql query, what you say

Comment: add this `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors',1);` on top of your PHP file, it will show you what naked eyes can't see :)

Comment: I have not written code in php file but it is written in post page directly

Comment: i mean the code i provided above in comment add that above the PHP code O provided in answer and check your error log file

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WordPress, you should use the WordPress DB API. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Complete code:

```
<form action="http://localhost/wordpress" method="POST">
    Name:<br /><input type="text" name="name" value=""><br />
    Roll No:<br /><input type="text" name="rollno" value="" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $wpdb->insert('test', array('name' => $_POST['name'], 'rollno' => $_POST['rollno']));
}
```

**Note:** above code is untested

Comment: Still entering blank rows, can you please tell platform's DB function for this case please.

Comment: @user3811050 https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows so you would use something like `$wpdb->insert('test', array('name' => $testname, 'rollno' => $testrollno));` Note you do not need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` in this case (WordPress will do it for you)

Comment: can you please update complete code, I shall be very very thankful to you

Comment: Sorry not adding anything and also not giving any error

Comment: @user3811050 where are you putting this code? I.e. how are you running it in WordPress?

Comment: I went to posts then new post then entered above code in body

Comment: @user3811050 lol ok... that isn't how it works. You can't run PHP code in a post. Please research WordPress Theme/Plugin Development.